# How can I read data from *mongo.UpdateResult type in Golang (UpdateOne, $addToSet)

Tags: mongodb, go

I am utilizing the Go MongoDB driver to find and update one record in MongoDB, which works as expected.  I am struggling with the return value from `collection.UpdateOne` (of type `*mongo.UpdateResult`).  Here is the function

```golang
func AddPaidByYYYYmm(id string, YYYYmm string) (int, error) {
    ctx := context.Background()
    _id, err := primitive.ObjectIDFromHex(id)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    if !CheckYearMonthFormat(YYYYmm) {
        return 0, errors.New("ill-formed date format; must be YYYY-mm")
    }
    result, err := collection.UpdateOne(ctx, bson.M{"_id": _id}, bson.M{"$addToSet": bson.M{"paid": YYYYmm}})
    fmt.Println(result)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    if result.MatchedCount == 0 {
        return 0, errors.New("no document matched id")
    }
    return 1, nil
}
```

Here are the three scenarios I am seeing and their respective return values (all of which are of type `*mongo.UpdateResult`):

1. Record not found, string not added to MongoDB: `&{0 0 0 <nil>}`
2. Record found, string added to the array in the db: `&{1 1 0 <nil>}`
3. Record found, string is already in db and not added: `&{1 0 0 <nil>}`

The issue is, I do not know how to read this data. Any guidance on how to get to this would be helpful. Please let me know if I have been unclear on anything or if anyone has any questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [doc for `mongo.UpdateResult`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#UpdateResult):

```golang
type UpdateResult struct {
    MatchedCount  int64       // The number of documents matched by the filter.
    ModifiedCount int64       // The number of documents modified by the operation.
    UpsertedCount int64       // The number of documents upserted by the operation.
    UpsertedID    interface{} // The _id field of the upserted document, or nil if no upsert was done.
}
```

1. Record not found, string not added to MongoDB: `&{0 0 0 <nil>}`

   `&mongo.UpdateResult{MatchedCount:0, ModifiedCount:0, UpsertedCount:0, UpsertedID:interface {}(nil)}`
2. Record found, string added to the array in the db: `&{1 1 0 <nil>}`

   `&mongo.UpdateResult{MatchedCount:1, ModifiedCount:1, UpsertedCount:0, UpsertedID:interface {}(nil)}`
3. Record found, string is already in db and not added: `&{1 0 0 <nil>}`

   `&mongo.UpdateResult{MatchedCount:1, ModifiedCount:0, UpsertedCount:0, UpsertedID:interface {}(nil)}`

The output is printed with `fmt.Printf("%#v\n", result)`, see https://pkg.go.dev/fmt.

```
%#v a Go-syntax representation of the value
```